# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - Is it possible to use cookie authentication when browser (IE11 and Edge) has cookies disabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm finding that I can, so I must be confused about cookies.

********** SETUP SECTION **********

I've done the following:

1. Visual Studio 2017: File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> Web Application (Model-View-Controller).  All defaults (so No Authentication, and Configure for HTTPS checked true).  Solution Explorer will look like this:

[image]

2. In Startup.cs, I modified ConfigureServices:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // THIS WAS COMMENTED OUT
       //services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
       //{
       //    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
       //    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
       //    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       //});

       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

       // THIS WAS ADDED
       services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
               options.Cookie.IsEssential = false;
               options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
           });
   }
   ```
3. In Startup.cs, I modified Configure:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       else
       {
           app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
           // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
           app.UseHsts();
       }

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseStaticFiles();
       // THIS WAS COMMENTED OUT
       //app.UseCookiePolicy();
       // THIS WAS ADDED
       app.UseAuthentication();

       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });
   }
   ```
4. In the class for the HomeController.cs that's created for you, I added an [Authorize] tag:

   ```
       [Authorize]
       public class HomeController : Controller
       {
   ```
5. I added a new class file to the Models folder called AccountModel.cs, this is what it looks like:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1.Models
   {
       public class LoginViewModel
       {
           [Required]
           [Display(Name = "Email")]
           [EmailAddress]
           public string Email { get; set; }

           [Required]
           [DataType(DataType.Password)]
           [Display(Name = "Password")]
           public string Password { get; set; }

           [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
           public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
6. I created a New folder called Data and added a new class file called ApplicationUser.cs:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1.Data
   {
       public class ApplicationUser
       {
           public string Email { get; set; }
           public string FullName { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
7. I added a new class file to the Controllers folder called AccountControleler.cs, this is what it looks like:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
   {
       public class AccountController : Controller
       {
           public IActionResult Login()
           {
               return View();
           }

           [HttpPost]
           [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
           public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
           {
               if (!ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   return View(model);
               }

               ApplicationUser appUser = await AuthenticateUser(model.Email, model.Password);

               if (appUser == null)
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                   return View(model);
               }

               List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
               {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUser.FullName),
                   new Claim("FullName", appUser.FullName),
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, appUser.Email),
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")
               };

               ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

               AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();

               await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                   new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                   authProperties);

               return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
           }

           private async Task<ApplicationUser> AuthenticateUser(string email, string password)
           {
               await Task.Delay(500);

               if (email == "so@test.com")
               {
                   return new ApplicationUser()
                   {
                       Email = "so@test.com",
                       FullName = "Stack Overflow"
                   };
               }
               else
               {
                   return null;
               }
           }

           private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
           {
               if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
               {
                   return Redirect(returnUrl);
               }
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
8. I created a New folder under the Views folder called Account and added a new class view called Login.cshtml:

   ```
   @model WebApplication1.Models.LoginViewModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
   }

   <h2 class="text-primary">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <section id="loginForm">
               @*https://dustinewers.com/how-to-build-html-helpers-like-html-beginform-in-asp-net-mvc/*@
               @*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.beginform?view=aspnetcore-2.2*@
               @*@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",TModel-routeValues,FormMethod.Post, bool?-AntiforgeryExtensions, TModel-htmlAttributes)*@
               @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, null, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
               {
                   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                   <h4 class="text-primary">Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                   <hr />
                   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   <div class="form-group">
                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                       <div class="col-md-10">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                       <div class="col-md-10">
                           @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                           <div class="checkbox">
                               @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                               @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                           <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" />
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <p>
                       @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                   </p>
                   @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                       <p>
                           @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                       </p>*@
               }
           </section>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
9. This is my browser settings (IE11) for cookies:

[image]

********** HERE IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE WHEN I RUN THE APP **********

Based on what I have set-up, when I run the app, it will take me to the Login Page and I can't get to any of the Home, or Privacy Views until I login.  This works.  That's not the issue.

I wanted to see what happened if I disabled cookies on the browser.  I know I disabled cookies correctly because if I try to log-in to facebook I will get the message "cookies required".  Yet, I can run my little test app to my hearts content and it will log me in, expire after 20 seconds (which would force me to log back in once I click a link), etc.  No loss of functionality, it works.

1. When I first run the app with cookies disabled:

[image]

2. Then, I log-in using my so@test.com user (type any password):

[image]

... And I can navigate to any view I want.

So what am I missing here?  Does cookie auth mean something different than the cookies associated with your browser?  Or this is some type of server cookie (vs a client cookie or something)?  Or does ASP.NET Core figure out a way around that in some way?

********** NEW INFORMATION **********

Looks like I should have tried another browser other than IE.  Firefox and Chrome did as expected, whereas IE and Edge ignores the fact that I have its cookies blocked.  Does anyone know why?  Is this some special magic for Microsoft browsers that other browsers don't have/get?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with your steps, it works correctly when the cookies is disabled and the request will be redirect to the Account controller all the time. Check web browser network tab to see whether there is any cookies in the request and reponse.

Comment: Just to clarify, at the very start, mine is always routed to the Account controller until I actually sign-in (my controller does actually perform await HttpContext.SignInAsync - oh, and I do have a Model class, as well).  Once I sign-in, I'm able to see any of the Contact, Home, or About pages.  All while my browser has cookies disabled

Comment: I really should have tried another browser besides IE11, I suppose.  Chrome and Firefox both do what you describe, keep redirecting to the Account controller.  Whereas IE11 ignores the fact that my settings are to block all cookies.

Comment: Edge too.  So Microsoft browsers work, even when cookies are blocked.  But other browsers don't (Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Fail to reproduce your issue with `IE 11 Version 11.55.17763.0`

Comment: I'm not making this up!  I started a project from scratch, to make sure I didn't miss a thing, and posted every piece of code I added to that project here (my original question was modified to show everything).  Then, I showed co-workers.  I'm surprised you don't.  Are you using my exact code?  My IE version is 11.967.16299.0, Update versions: 11.0.110 (KB4486474)

Comment: Check whether you could reproduce with this [project](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3iGbacCr5zL0uGqOk)

Comment: I will.  My kids got me sick and I missed a day at work and am getting caught up on other things ... but will definitely get back to this.